# peewee.OperationalError running a query

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I'm stumped trying to identify the cause of an exception generated when I run the below code. Any help would be appreciated.

Note that the error is actually reported as an SQL syntax error by sqlite.

The db is sqlite version 3.7.17 and I'm using peewee version 3.13.3 with Python 3.6.8. OS is Centos 7.

```
from peewee import *
from covid.models import Confirmed
query = Confirmed.select(
    fn.SUM(Confirmed.count)
    .over(
        order_by=[Confirmed.date],
        start=Window.preceding(3)
    )
    .alias('rsum')
).where(Confirmed.uid == 84036061)
print(query)
for q in query:
    print(q)
```

where the Confirmed Model is:

```
class Confirmed(BaseModel):
    uid = ForeignKeyField(Domain)
    date = DateField()
    count = IntegerField()
```

And the output is:

```
SELECT SUM("t1"."count") OVER (ORDER BY "t1"."date" ROWS 3 PRECEDING) AS "rsum" FROM "confirmed" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."uid_id" = 84036061)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/x.py", line 14, in <module>
    for q in query:
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 6797, in __iter__
    self.execute()
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1886, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1957, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2129, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3112, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3106, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2873, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 183, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/cp/sw/make/covid/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: From [sqlite doc:](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history) "_Window function support was first added to SQLite with release version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15)_"

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I will upgrade.

Comment: The upgrade solved the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As [DinoCoderSaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577076/dinocodersaurus) correctly pointed out, the Window function support is not available with SQLite version 3.7.17 that comes preinstalled with CentOS 7.

For the benefit of others that may encounter the same issue, here is how I resolved the problem:

To use the current SQLite version, I installed it in the app's venv by doing:

```
pip install pysqlite3-binary
```

(For more information about venv see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

SQLite is widely used by CentOS so replacing the system-wide version in /usr/bin is not a good idea for backward-compatibility reasons.

I should also note that when I tried:

```
pip install pysqlite3  # Instead of pysqlite3-binary
```

the installation completed "successfully" BUT when I tried unistalling:

```
pip uninstall pysqlite3
```

pip issued this warning:

WARNING: Skipping pysqlite3 as it is not installed.